# How to add onfocus function to js instead of add it in textarea tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello every one i have below code and i need to to add onfocus function in javascript instead of adding it in textarea tag because it is not secure if i add it in textarea tag

Also make js code work by class of textarea (class="limittext")

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Limit Textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">

textarea{
width:400px;
height:200px
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">


var alert_title='Input Restriction';

function limitTextarea(el,maxLines,maxChar){
if(!el.x){
el.x=uniqueInt();
el.onblur=function(){clearInterval(window['int'+el.x])}
}
window['int'+el.x]=setInterval(function(){
var lines=el.value.replace(/\r/g,'').split('\n'),
i=lines.length,
lines_removed,
char_removed;
if(maxLines&&i>maxLines){
alert('You can not enter\nmore than '+maxLines+' lines');
lines=lines.slice(0,maxLines);
lines_removed=1
}
if(maxChar){
i=lines.length;
while(i-->0)if(lines[i].length>maxChar){
lines[i]=lines[i].slice(0,maxChar);
char_removed=1
}
if(char_removed)alert('You can not enter more\nthan '+maxChar+' characters per line')
}
if(char_removed||lines_removed)el.value=lines.join('\n')
},50);
}

function uniqueInt(){
var num,maxNum=100000;
if(!uniqueInt.a||maxNum<=uniqueInt.a.length)uniqueInt.a=[];
do num=Math.ceil(Math.random()*maxNum);
while(uniqueInt.a.hasMember(num))
uniqueInt.a[uniqueInt.a.length]=num;
return num
}

Array.prototype.hasMember=function(testItem){
var i=this.length;
while(i-->0)if(testItem==this[i])return 1;
return 0
};

function set_ie_alert(){
window.alert=function(msg_str){
vb_alert(msg_str)
}
}

</script>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbs">

set_ie_alert()

Function vb_alert(msg_str)
MsgBox msg_str,vbOKOnly+vbInformation+vbApplicationModal,alert_title
End Function

</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea class="limittext" onfocus="limitTextarea(this,2,0)" wrap="off">some text</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event listener in javascript with `.addEventListener()` and get all the elements with the class "limittext" with `document.getElementsByClassName()`. What you can do is to find all the elements with the class of interest, and then iterate through them and set an event listener to each of them. Something like this should work:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('limittext');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('focus', function() {
     limitTextArea(elements[i],2,0);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. i have tried that but isn't work

Comment: If you just try to `.alert()` instead of calling `.limitTextArea()`. Does anything happen? @user3772028

Comment: Isn't work

can you edit it on this link https://jsfiddle.net/zf155z9y/1/

Comment: @user3772028 Make sure the DOM is loaded before you try to add the event listeners

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this the best solution or not. I failed to make it work by class but i enabled to make that code work by using ID and do some editions on js code

Thank you for all try to help me

https://jsfiddle.net/zf155z9y/3/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Limit Textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">

textarea{
width:400px;
height:200px
}

</style>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbs">

set_ie_alert()

Function vb_alert(msg_str)
MsgBox msg_str,vbOKOnly+vbInformation+vbApplicationModal,alert_title
End Function

</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="myForm" wrap="off">some text</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">

var alert_title='Input Restriction';
var x = document.getElementById('myForm');
x.addEventListener("focusin", limitTextarea);

function limitTextarea(){
var el = this;
var maxLines = 5;
var maxChar = 0;
if(!el.x){
el.x=uniqueInt();
el.onblur=function(){clearInterval(window['int'+el.x])}
}
window['int'+el.x]=setInterval(function(){
var lines=el.value.replace(/\r/g,'').split('\n'),
i=lines.length,
lines_removed,
char_removed;
if(maxLines&&i>maxLines){
alert('You can not enter\nmore than '+maxLines+' lines');
lines=lines.slice(0,maxLines);
lines_removed=1
}
if(maxChar){
i=lines.length;
while(i-->0)if(lines[i].length>maxChar){
lines[i]=lines[i].slice(0,maxChar);
char_removed=1
}
if(char_removed)alert('You can not enter more\nthan '+maxChar+' characters per line')
}
if(char_removed||lines_removed)el.value=lines.join('\n')
},50);
}

function uniqueInt(){
var num,maxNum=100000;
if(!uniqueInt.a||maxNum<=uniqueInt.a.length)uniqueInt.a=[];
do num=Math.ceil(Math.random()*maxNum);
while(uniqueInt.a.hasMember(num))
uniqueInt.a[uniqueInt.a.length]=num;
return num
}

Array.prototype.hasMember=function(testItem){
var i=this.length;
while(i-->0)if(testItem==this[i])return 1;
return 0
};

function set_ie_alert(){
window.alert=function(msg_str){
vb_alert(msg_str)
}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```